# Create a GPFS Administrative account

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, cluster

I try to install GPFS on Windows Server 2008 R2, after successfully install GPFS I want to use the GPFS Command Prompt. But when I type in some Commands there comes a error: "mmstartup cannot execute - Permission denied"

I think I do something wrong while [create the Administrative Account](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/hpccentral/GPFS+Quick+Start+guide+for+Windows) but I don't know what kind of error it is. I start the Service as User DOMAIN\root and set the Profildirectory with grand access to user root. Now I login as user root but get the Error I show at top.

Any suggestion to debug this Installation?

I can solve this Problem with following Steps from [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=312484)

> After installed GPFS Client, I had to change permissions to the
>   following directories before mmstartup can run.
>
> Launch C Shell
>
> ```
> chown -R root /var/mmfs  
> chown -R root /var/adm/log 
> chown -R root /var/adm/ras  
> chown -R root /usr/lpp/mmfs
> ```

There are no errors for wrong Permission now.

Answer (score 0):

[kockiren](https://superuser.com/users/98737/kockiren), I'm new to writing answers here, but I've heard from other threads that it is valid to answer your own question. If you want to create your own answer and accept it, please do. Until then, I think it's helpful to show an answer post, in case anyone has this issue but doesn't see the answer buried in the original post.

---

I can solve this Problem with following Steps from [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=312484)

> After installed GPFS Client, I had to change permissions to the following directories before mmstartup can run.
>
> Launch C Shell
>
> > chown -R root /var/mmfs
> >     chown -R root /var/adm/log 
> >     chown -R root /var/adm/ras
> >     chown -R root /usr/lpp/mmfs

There are no errors for wrong Permission now.

thx Rene